# what is -nan(ind) and how do I resolve the error?

Tags: c++, function, logic, nan, runge-kutta

Instead of getting numerical values, I get `-nan(ind)` when the number of iterations increases. I have applied the 4th order Runge Kutta method in the program, and the functions are given in `dvdt` and `drdt`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double dvdt(double t, double v);
double drdt(double t, double r);

double RKv(double t, double v, double h);
double RKr(double t, double r, double h);

double xo = 0;    //initial X position
double yo = 0;    //initial Y position
double x1;      //final X position
double y11;      //final Y position
double ti = 0;  //initial time = 0
double tf = 30;      //time entered
double dt = 0.01;   //time step (iteration time)
double rud = 0;   //rudder angle
double m = 53330750;   //mass of submarine (Kg)
double Iz = 57.5;     //moment of inertia of submarine (kg.m^2)
double xg = -0.012;   //x position of COG
double yg = 0;     // position of COG
double u = 10; // surge velocity
double v, vo = 0; //sway velocity
double r, ro = 0; // yaw rate
double psio = 0; //initial ship heading
double psi1;  //final ship heading
double rudmax; // max rudder angle
double au; //surge acceleration
double av; // sway acceleration
double ar; //angular acceleration
double X; //surge force
double Y; //sway force
double N; //turning moment
double h = 1;


//matrices
double M[2][2];         //mass matrix
double Nu0[2][2];       //inertia matrix ig
double b[2][1];         //force matrix
double A[2][1];         //acceleration matrix
double V[2][1];         //velocity matrix


//maneuvering and hydrodynamic coefficents
double Xu1 = -1.0467 * pow(10, -3);
double Yv1 = -23.889 * pow(10, -3);
double Yr1 = -1.0510 * pow(10, -3);
double Nv1 = 1.1531 * pow(10, -3);
double Nr1 = -0.50717 * pow(10, -3);
double Xu = -2.8763 * pow(10, -3);
double Yv = -38.948 * pow(10, -3);
double Yr = 2.0031 * pow(10, -3);
double Nv = -14.287 * pow(10, -3);
double Nr = -4.2267 * pow(10, -3);
double Yrud = 1.4308 * pow(10, -3);
double Nrud = -0.71540 * pow(10, -3);

double a1 = m - Yv1;
double b1 = m * xg - Yr1;
double a2 = m * xg - Yr1;
double b2 = Iz - Nr1;
double det = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;

double q1 = (-Yv * (Iz - Nr1) / det);
double q2 = ((m - Xu1) * u - Yr) * (-m * xg - Yr1) / det;
double q3 = ((Xu1 - Yv1) * u - Nv) * (-m * xg + Yr) / det;
double q4 = ((m * xg - Yr1) * u - Nr)* (m - Yr1) / det;
int main()
{
    while (ti <= tf)
    {
        vo = RKv(ti, vo, h);
        ro = RKr(ti, ro, h);

        v += vo;
        r += ro;
        
        cout << "v = " << v << "    " << "r = " << r << "\n";
        ti = ti + 0.5;
        rud += 0.05;
    }
}

double RKv(double t, double v, double h)
{
    double k1, k2, k3, k4, k5;

    


    for (int i = 0.1; i <= h; i++)
    {
        
        k1 = h * dvdt(t, v);
        k2 = h * dvdt(t + 0.5 * h, v + 0.5 * k1);
        k3 = h * dvdt(t + 0.5 * h, v + 0.5 * k2);
        k4 = h * dvdt(t + h, v + k3);

        
        t = t + h;
        v = v + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);

        
    }
    return v;
}

double RKr(double t, double r, double h)
{
    double k1, k2, k3, k4, k5;

    for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++)
    {
        
        k1 = h * drdt(t, r);
        k2 = h * drdt(t + 0.5 * h, r + 0.5 * k1);
        k3 = h * drdt(t + 0.5 * h, r + 0.5 * k2);
        k4 = h * drdt(t + h, r + k3);

        
        t = t + h;
        r = r + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4);

    }
    return r;
}


double dvdt(double t, double v)
{
//  return(-Yrud * rud - (-Yv * (Iz - Nr1) / det * v + ((m - Xu1) * u - Yr) * (-m * xg - Yr1) / det * r));
    return(-Yrud * rud - q1 * v + q2 * r);
    
}

double drdt(double t, double r)
{
    //return(-Nrud * rud - (((Xu1 - Yv1) * u - Nv) * (-m * xg + Yr) / det * v + ((m * xg - Yr1) * u - Nr) * (m - Yr1) / det * r));
    return(-Nrud * rud - q3 * v + q4 * r);
    
}
```

Here are the results of the program. I get numerical values for the first few iterations, after which I get `-nan(ind)`:

[image]

Comment: Nan is not-a-number. My guess is that your iterative scheme diverges and overflows.

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: You should be getting a warning from the compiler the line `for (int i = 0.1; i <= h; i++)` - `warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 0.1 to 0 [-Wliteral-conversion]`  Also quite a few unused variables / parameters and some shadowing - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3xa5o3Y1e - get the program to compile clean.

Comment: Your RK4 is wrong. If you did not define r,v also as global variables, you would get a corresponding compilation error in drdt, dvdt. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rk4+coupled+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+or+%5Bc%5D for examples of applying RK4 to coupled systems.

Comment: The return value from the RK4 procedures is already the incremented value, not the increment. Using it as increment is another error. You should also unify what the time step is. At the moment you have dt=0.01 (not in use), h=1 and a hard-coded 0.05 increment of ti.

Answer (score 1):

Your application of RK4 is wrong. While the copied code for the RK4 step is good, the only systems you can successfully solve with it are uncoupled scalar DE `r'(t)=drdt(t,r)` and `v'(t)=dvdt(t,v)`.

That what you try is impossible should be visible where the derivative functions are coded. You are using variables that do not occur in the argument list of the function. And if they were in the argument list, they would need a corresponding increment in the stages of the RK4 step. If you did not define `r` and `v` as global variables, you would get a compilation error in `drdt`, `dvdt` for undefined variables.

The return value from the RK4-step procedures is already the incremented value, not the increment or offset. Using it in the time loop as increment is another error.

You should also unify what the time step is. At the moment you have `dt=0.01` (not in use), `h=1` and a hard-coded `0.05` increment of `ti`.

See the search results http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rk4+coupled+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+or+%5Bc%5D for examples of applying RK4 to coupled systems.

Answer (score 0):

You went out of the number range, for ex. how to solve it, you could use `long double` type instead of regular `double`.